# Market making in linear products, analogous to a short straddle under simplifying assumptions?

Tags: market-making

To preface, I am not a market-maker or trader, but I have an ok understanding of options and classic vanilla option theory.

For a market maker providing quotes at a single level (i.e 99 bid - 101 offer), they are able to monetise their spread whilst market orders coming into the market are less than the posted amounts, an amount $q_{b,a}$, and there is sufficiently balanced flow. If the price moves beyond the bid/offer, then the MM has a delta of $q_{b,a}$, leaving a risk profile of $q_{b,a} \,\ \cdot |{\Delta S}|$.

In this simplistic model, the PnL is: $$ PnL = S_t \cdot spread \cdot q \,\ - [q \cdot abs(S_{t+1} - S_t) \,\ | S_{t+1} < bid_t \ or \ S_{t+1} > offer_t] $$

To me this seems similar to selling a straddle. Does anybody have any improvements to offer or papers to suggest? Again I reiterate I am very unfamiliar with intricacies of market making, and am aware that this model does not factor out into the multi-period, or under the presence of multiple market makers with competing bid/offers. I am curious as I am unable to find papers which visualise the relationship between the underlying movement at some time-slice, t, and PnL. Is this because it does not exist?

I should imagine that at the point where a market maker is quoting at multiple depths simultaneously, that there is an effect analogous to gamma where the MM picks up delta as the market moves away from their quotes. From an options perspective (or even just non-linear payoffs) this seems to point to a notion of implied volatility, fair spread width, and fair quoting amounts under some distribution of trade sizes, and underlying volatility. Is there some way to Taylor expand market maker PnL?

Thanks!